# Mongodb find objects where nested array's object satisfies multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get groups for a user only if the user is part of that group and its membership is `true`.
Here is the group schema

```
{
        "isDefault": false,
        "users": [
            {
                "membership": true,
                "userId": "asd1234"
            },
            {
                "membership": false,
                "userId": "asdio21038028355"
            },
            {
                "membership": false,
                "userId": "as2398asjdhj"
            }
        ],
        "uuid": "c4vxitr33a9hb19n05iuqxlv1ycp47",
}
```

This is what I'm trying to get Groups for the user

```
Group.find({ 'users.membership': true, 'users.userId': 'asdio21038028355' })
```

Expected results should be an empty array but it is returning the above group as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match an array item by multiple fields use $elemMatch, otherwise only one match needs to be fulfilled to return the doc.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UB-Z0GX-CYq

```
Group.find({
  users: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "membership": true,
      "userId": "asdio21038028355"
    }
  }
})
```